# How to make a weighted frequency table with multiple variables (NOT crossed) in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a lot of variables and 2 weighting columns.

```
scale1 <- c(5,NA,2,1)
scale2 <- c(NA,4,NA,3)
scale3 <- c(3,NA,5,NA)
scale4 <- c(2,1,NA,5)
df<- data.frame(scale1,scale2,scale3,scale4)
df
> df
  v1 v2 v3 weight1 weight2
1  1  1  0     0.5     1.1
2  1  0  0     0.5     1.1
3  0  1  0     1.2     0.3
4  0  0  0     1.2     0.3
>
```

As I am trying to construct weighted frequency table, I use

```
count(df, v1, wt = weight1 * weight2)
```

However, I want to produce weighted frequency table for a lot of variables in my data, but I don't want to cross them as this code would do

```
count(df, v1, v2, wt = weight1 * weight2)
```

I want to make the table for each variable, as the following code would do. But I don't want to write them one by one because there is a lot of variables in my actual data frame.

```
count(df, v1, wt = weight1 * weight2)
count(df, v2, wt = weight1 * weight2)
count(df, v3, wt = weight1 * weight2)
```

Also, I am trying to export the tables as a CSV file at once.

Is there an efficient way to make the table and export as CSV?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply it to all the columns that are not `weight1|2`

```r
cols <- colnames(df)[!grepl("weight", colnames(df))]
lapply(cols, function(x) count( x=df, !!as.name(x), wt = weight1 * weight2))
```

**Another way**

```r
cols <- sapply(colnames(df)[!grepl("weight", colnames(df))], as.name)
lapply(cols, count,  x=df, wt = weight1 * weight2)
```

```r
$v1
  v1    n
1  0 0.72
2  1 1.10

$v2
  v2    n
1  0 0.91
2  1 0.91

$v3
  v3    n
1  0 1.82
```

**`purrr`**

```r
colnames(df)[!grepl("weight", colnames(df))] %>%
 purrr::map(~ count(x=df, !!as.name(.x), wt=weight1 * weight2))
```

**Edit**
making it into a single table and exporting it to csv:

```r
cols <- colnames(df)[!grepl("weight", colnames(df))]

lapply(cols, function(x) count(x=df, !!as.name(x), wt = weight1 * weight2) %>% mutate(var=x, value=!!as.name(x), !!as.name(x):=NULL)) %>%
 bind_rows -> df
df
```

```r
     n var value
1 0.72  v1     0
2 1.10  v1     1
3 0.91  v2     0
4 0.91  v2     1
5 1.82  v3     0
```

#### Edit pure dplyr way

```r
df %>%
 # group_by all the other columns count by default tallies by the grouping columns
 group_by(across(!starts_with("weight"))) %>%
 # count with weights
  count(wt=weight1 * weight2) %>%
 # pivot into longer format
   pivot_longer(!n) %>%
 # group by name and value
    group_by(name, value) %>%
 # sum up the occurrences
     summarise(n = sum(n))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name  value     n
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 v1        0  0.72
2 v1        1  1.1 
3 v2        0  0.91
4 v2        1  0.91
5 v3        0  1.82
```